# Error Code: 1826. Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'menu_ibfk_1'

Tags: mysql, sql, compiler-errors, runtime-error, error-code

I am writing a code on MySQL and it's giving me errors.

This is my code and it's giving me the error - "Error Code: 1826. Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'menu_ibfk_1' "

When I give a different constraint name, it give me the error - "Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'menu_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'menu'"

```
create database WasteManagement;
CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Faculty_login ( 
Faculty_ID int(9) NOT NULL  ,
FName varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
Department varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
Password varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Faculty_ID) );

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Student_login ( 
Enrollment_No int(11) NOT NULL , 
SName varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
Course varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
Password varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Enrollment_No) );

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Staff_login ( 
Staff_ID int(9) NOT NULL  ,
CName varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
Username varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
Password varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Staff_ID) );

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Menu ( 
Staff_ID int(9) NOT NULL,
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish)
#FOREIGN KEY (Staff_ID) References Menu(Staff_ID) 
);

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Demand1 ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
S_demand BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE, 
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish, S_demand),
KEY d1 (datee),
KEY t1 (Timee),
KEY dish1 (Dish),
#KEY `AuthorID` (`AuthorID`),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu(Dish));

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Demand2 ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
F_demand BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE, 
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish, F_demand),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu(Dish));

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Feedback1 ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
eaten_by1 int(7) NOT NULL, 
s_rating int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish, eaten_by1, s_rating),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu(Dish));

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Feedback2 ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
eaten_by2 int(7) NOT NULL, 
f_rating int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish, eaten_by2, f_rating),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu (Dish));

CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Wastage ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
Produced_qty int(7) NOT NULL, 
Wasted_qty int(7) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Time, Dish, Produced_qty, Wasted_qty),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),
CONSTRAINT `menu_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu(Dish));
```

This is the snapshot of MySQL output

[MySQL output snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFeGC.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you could simplify the example to just two or three tables.

Comment: Either skip the constraint names, or have unique ones for each foreign key.

Comment: it still gives errors without the constraint names - Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'demand1_ibfk_2' in the referenced table 'menu'

Comment: That's another problem. As Gordon said, minimize the problem - [mcve]. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, mysql doesn't allow multiple foreign keys with the same name. As for your 2nd error, what is the DDL (create statement) of your `Menu` table?

Comment: For the second error, im keeping the same code, for menu table,    for the demand table, the create statement is - CREATE TABLE WasteManagement.Demand1 ( 
Datee date NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
Timee varchar(10) NOT NULL,  
Dish varchar(30) NOT NULL,   
S_demand BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,    
PRIMARY KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish, S_demand),   
KEY d1 (date),   
KEY t1 (Timee),   
KEY dish1 (Dish),   
FOREIGN KEY (Datee) References Menu(Datee),   
FOREIGN KEY (Timee) References Menu(Timee),   
FOREIGN KEY (Dish) References Menu(Dish));

Comment: Count how many times the substring **CONSTRAINT \`menu_ibfk_1\`** is present in your code. Whereas the constraint name must be unique over a database at least. PS. I do not see the reason to specify constraint name explicitly at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key must reference the complete key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Datee, Timee, Dish) References Menu(Datee, Timee, Dish)
```

And each constraint must have its own, unique name.

Comment: ... + according composite index in `Menu` table.